# how can I add sampler after sampler in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter to test at my dev server.

The Scenario is like This.
0. Turn OFF all firewalls both local PC(so called, HOST) and client PC(so called, CLIENT)

1. Turn on Jmeter at my HOST
   --> add Thread Group, bzm-Parellel Controller. I am not certain at this point
2. Connect to CLIENT (once)
   -> maybe, by SSH Command or REMOTE Start
3. execute my test script at CLIENT (several times, more than 100 times)
   -> such as, 'ls' 'pwd' 'mkdir dir123' 'ls' **IN A ROW!!**
   -> maybe, by OS Process Sampler. I am not certain at this point
4. get result of (3) at my HOST jmeter by View Results Tree

This is the scenario that I Thought

Can anyone help me with this issue.
Cuz, there's too many Samplers and less information, I'm suffering such a tough moments.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

0. Turning off firewall is not the best idea, just open the port you will be using, [default port for SSH is 22](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/nsm2012.2/topics/concept/security-service-port-number-ssh-telnet-connection-nsm-overview.html) and normally it's getting opened more or less automatically when you install OpenSSH server
1. I don't think you need Parallel Controller, it has very specific use cases like simulating AJAX requests, it will be sufficient to specify the desired number of users/loops/test duration on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. Remote start is for JMeter [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), if you want to run a shell command on the client use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) or [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler, see [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details.
3. The same is for point 2, if you need to create a directory depending on your HOST and CLIENT operating systems you need to choose one of the aforementioned samplers. Just be aware that only first operation/iteration succeeds, all the subsequent attempts you will get `cannot create directory ‘dir123’: File exists`. I'm also not certain what you're trying to test here? SSH server performance? Operating system performance? Network performance?
4. If you add View Results Tree listener to your Test Plan and run your test in GUI mode it will automatically catch all the Samplers results

Comment: Thank you for you comment, and Sorry for my poor explanation.
I want to connect to the CLIENT just one time by jmeter. And then after the connection, I want to execute my shell script(.sh) for numerous times, also by jmeter.
The shell script will connect to my blockchain network and get data from there.
My Main purpose of test is to get TPS and error rate of that executed shell script.

thank you for your help